# Issue in getting connectionstring from ADO Connection in SSIS

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ssis

It took me hours to find out the real problem. Here is the problem.

I have a VB.Net script task in a SSIS 2005 package. Purpose of the script task is to do bulk insert from one database into another (in different servers). I am using `SQlBulkCopy` class present in .Net to do the insert.  It works fine when I use windows authentication.

Now I made it as `SQL Server Authentication`   and used `expressions` to create connection string from a  variable value stored in config file. SSIS is successfully able to acquire the ADO connection – but when I extract connection string from the `connection object` it doesn’t give the password –it swallows the password.

```vb
Dim destinationConnection As New SqlConnection()
destinationConnection = DirectCast(TryCast(Dts.Connections("ADOACIConnection").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlConnection), SqlConnection)

Dim destinationConnectionString As String = destinationConnection.ConnectionString
MessageBox.Show(destinationConnectionString)  'It is not getting password when using SQL Server Authentication
PerformBulkCopy(tableName, sourceConnection, destinationConnectionString)
```

Question

1. How can we get the connection string with password?

**CODE**

```vb
Public Sub PerformBulkCopy(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal sourceConnection As SqlConnection, ByVal destinationConnectionString As String)
    Dim dtSource As DataTable
    dtSource = New System.Data.DataTable()
    dtSource = GetSourceDataTable(tableName, sourceConnection)


    Using sbc As New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnectionString)
        sbc.DestinationTableName = tableName
        sbc.WriteToServer(dtSource)
    End Using
End Sub


Public Function GetSourceDataTable(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal sourceConnection As SqlConnection) As DataTable

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("uspGetDataForAchival")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TableName", tableName))
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = sourceConnection

    Dim dap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dap.Fill(ds)
    Return ds.Tables(0)

End Function

Public Sub Main()

    Dim tableName As String = Dts.Variables("User::CurrentTable").Value.ToString()
    Dim sourceConnection As New SqlConnection()

    Try

        sourceConnection = DirectCast(TryCast(Dts.Connections("ADOSourceConnection").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlConnection), SqlConnection)

        Dim destinationConnection As New SqlConnection()
        destinationConnection = DirectCast(TryCast(Dts.Connections("ADOACIConnection").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlConnection), SqlConnection)

        Dim destinationConnectionString As String = destinationConnection.ConnectionString
        MessageBox.Show(destinationConnectionString)  
        PerformBulkCopy(tableName, sourceConnection, destinationConnectionString)

        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim exceptionVariable As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables = Nothing
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::ScriptException", exceptionVariable)
        exceptionVariable("User::ScriptException").Value = ex.Message
        exceptionVariable.Unlock()
        Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Task Name", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Seen this excellent post by [Todd McDermid](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2011/05/use-connections-properly-in-ssis-script.html)?

Comment: `DirectCast(TryCast(Dts.Connections("ADOACIConnection").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlConnection), SqlConnection)` This is strange construct. And what if your `tryCast` will return `nothing`??? Another one `dtSource = New System.Data.DataTable()
    dtSource = GetSourceDataTable(tableName, sourceConnection)` - the first line there is useless

Comment: I believe there is a option that allow to save the password in the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thansk @billinkc for adding reference to Todd McDermid's Blog Post about [Use Connections Properly in an SSIS Script Task](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2011/05/use-connections-properly-in-ssis-script.html)

Another article I read is [MSDN - SSIS Team Blog - Accessing OLEDB Connection Managers in a Script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/08/22/accessing-oledb-connection-managers-in-a-script.aspx)

Finally I modified the code to resolve the issue and to make the connections as per the above mentioned blog post. Instead of creating connection from connection string, I just passed the connection object to do the SqlBulkCopy. It worked fine.

```
    Public Sub PerformBulkCopy(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal sourceConnection As SqlConnection, ByVal destinationConnection As SqlConnection)
    Dim dtSource As DataTable
    dtSource = New System.Data.DataTable()
    dtSource = GetSourceDataTable(tableName, sourceConnection)


    Using sbc As New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
        sbc.DestinationTableName = tableName
        sbc.WriteToServer(dtSource)
    End Using
End Sub


Public Function GetSourceDataTable(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal sourceConnection As SqlConnection) As DataTable

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("uspGetDataForAchival")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TableName", tableName))
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = sourceConnection

    Dim dap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dap.Fill(ds)
    Return ds.Tables(0)

End Function

Public Sub Main()

    Dim tableName As String = Dts.Variables("User::CurrentTable").Value.ToString()
    Dim sourceConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim destinationConnection As SqlConnection

    Try
        ' Retrieve the reference to the managed connection'
        Dim cmSource As ConnectionManager
        cmSource = Dts.Connections("ADOSourceConnection")
        sourceConnection = DirectCast(cmSource.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

        Dim cmDestination As ConnectionManager
        cmDestination = Dts.Connections("ADOACIConnection")
        destinationConnection = DirectCast(cmDestination.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

        Dim destinationConnectionString As String = destinationConnection.ConnectionString
        MessageBox.Show(destinationConnectionString)
        PerformBulkCopy(tableName, sourceConnection, destinationConnection)

        'Release Connection'
        cmSource.ReleaseConnection(sourceConnection)
        cmDestination.ReleaseConnection(destinationConnection)

        'Success'
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success


    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim exceptionVariable As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables = Nothing
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::ScriptException", exceptionVariable)
        exceptionVariable("User::ScriptException").Value = ex.Message
        exceptionVariable.Unlock()
        Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Task Name", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
     End Try

    End Sub
```